# Large file execution on apache2

Tags: apache, perl

I have a perl code which decrypts large movie files(which are encrypted). It runs fine and decrypts a movie completely when I run it from my linux terminal, but when I test it on apache on my local host, it decrypts only a small part of the movie.

If the movie is for like 2:30 mins, it decrypts only first 12 minutes of the movie.

Also, it works works fine with short length movies.

Does apache2 have any server limitations? or there can be any other problem? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably hitting a timeout of the server. Check [Timeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout) for the apache setting.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. It decrypted exactly like before.

Comment: How long does it take before the decrypt stops? (not the movie but the script)

Comment: It takes around 6-8 mins to decrpyt that movie file. I didn't exactly understand your question.

Comment: Well your script only decrypts the first 12 minutes of the movie. So after a certain amount of time, the decryption stops/fails. The amount of time may indicate which timeout is interrupting your script.